# How to use JNI with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-up-jni-development-in-gradle-project.html) to use JNI with gradle project.

But , I have this [ERROR](https://github.com/vladsoroka/GradleJniSample/issues/4).

Then , I followed this [project](https://github.com/eskatos/jni-library-sample) to use jni with gradle project.

But , I have this [ERROR](https://github.com/eskatos/jni-library-sample/issues/5).

I want to use JNI with gradle project to build native lib for windows, linux and mac.

How can I use JNI with gradle ?

Give a simple JNI tutorial with gradle.

Comment: By itself, Gradle does not know to generate  header files for Java files with `native` methods

Comment: How Can I solve this following issue ? https://github.com/vladsoroka/GradleJniSample/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle Java plugin – by default – [generates header files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:headerOutputDirectory) for any Java files that contain native methods.

The default output path is `${project.buildDir}/generated/sources/headers/${sourceDirectorySet.name}/${sourceSet.name}`, so for the `gcj` project linked from your first link, I get the following file:

```
./build/generated/sources/headers/java/main/HelloWorld.h
```

In order to make the Gradle cpp plugin find that, you need to set its include search path to (a part of) the above path.

Comment: I am new to JNI . I still can't understand what you say about?  Gradle file : https://github.com/vladsoroka/GradleJniSample/blob/master/build.gradle if run 'test' in gradle the output comes 'Helloworld'. But , My doubt is how can I run this in Main class. Project : https://github.com/vladsoroka/GradleJniSample  and my issue : https://github.com/vladsoroka/GradleJniSample/issues/4

Comment: You need to also set the `java.library.path` property when you run the program normally.

Comment: How can I set `java.library.path` property?

Comment: I tried this below ans but same error occurs

`task local {
    run { systemProperty "java.library.path", "local" }
}
bootRun.mustRunAfter local`
Then run gradle command as:

`gradle bootRun local`  project link : github.com/vladsoroka/GradleJniSample

Comment: Sorry, your question has nothing to do with JNI, beyond the need to set this one property. I tried my best to help you but I don't know how to solve the underlying Gradle problem.